# How to fetch data API to dropdown

Tags: flutter, dropdown

how do I call the API data into the dropdown I have done several times, when I used local data in the form of a String list I managed to call the data, but when I tried to call from the API data the result was empty and the results in the dropdown did not display any data

```
 Future<List<Agama>> getAgama() async {
    String url = Constant.baseURL;
    String token = await UtilSharedPreferences.getToken();
    final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse(
        '$url/auth/mhs_siakad/dosen',
      ),
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
      },
    );
    print(response.statusCode);
    print(response.body);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final result =
          json.decode(response.body)['nm_agama'] as Map<String, dynamic>;
      UserBiodata agama = UserBiodata.fromJson(result);
      List<Agama> l = agama.data ?? [];
      return l;
    } else {
      throw Exception();
    }
  }
```

in widget

```
 List<Agama>? religion = [];



 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    BiodataProvider().getAgama();
  }

  var dropdownAgama;
...
     FutureBuilder(
                future: BiodataProvider().getBiodata(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    print(' ini Agama $religion');
                    return Column(
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          snapshot.data!.data!.name.toString(),
                          style: bold5,
                        ),
                        DropdownButton(
                          hint: const Text('Religion'),
                          items: religion!.map((item) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem(
                              value: item.nmAgama.toString(),
                              child: Text(item.idAgama.toString()),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                          onChanged: (newVal) {
                            setState(() {
                              dropdownAgama = newVal;
                            });
                          },
                          value: dropdownAgama,
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  } else {
                    return const Text('No Data');
                  }
                }),
...
```

this is the model i am using which is converted from API

```
class Agama {
  String? id;
  String? idAgama;
  String? nmAgama;
  String? createdAt;
  String? updatedAt;
  dynamic createdBy;
  dynamic updatedBy;

  Agama(
      {this.id,
      this.idAgama,
      this.nmAgama,
      this.createdAt,
      this.updatedAt,
      this.createdBy,
      this.updatedBy});

  Agama.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    idAgama = json['id_agama'];
    nmAgama = json['nm_agama'];
    createdAt = json['created_at'];
    updatedAt = json['updated_at'];
    createdBy = json['created_by'];
    updatedBy = json['updated_by'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['id'] = id;
    data['id_agama'] = idAgama;
    data['nm_agama'] = nmAgama;
    data['created_at'] = createdAt;
    data['updated_at'] = updatedAt;
    data['created_by'] = createdBy;
    data['updated_by'] = updatedBy;
    return data;
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share the code for `Agama`?

Comment: i'm update this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you are not assigning your api data to the

```
List<Agama>? religion;
```

you can solve this by either mapping your snapshot data directly:

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    BiodataProvider().getAgama();
  }

  var dropdownAgama;
...
     FutureBuilder(
                future: BiodataProvider().getBiodata(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    print(' ini Agama $religion');
                    return Column(
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          snapshot.data!.data!.name.toString(),
                          style: bold5,
                        ),
                        DropdownButton(
                          hint: const Text('Religion'),
                          items:  snapshot.data!.data!.map((item) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem(
                              value: item.nmAgama.toString(),
                              child: Text(item.idAgama.toString()),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                          onChanged: (newVal) {
                            setState(() {
                              dropdownAgama = newVal;
                            });
                          },
                          value: dropdownAgama,
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  } else {
                    return const Text('No Data');
                  }
                }),
```

or

by assigning the snapshot data to your list:

```
    List<Agama>? religion = [];
    
    
    
     @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        BiodataProvider().getAgama();
      }
    
      var dropdownAgama;
    ...
         FutureBuilder(
                    future: BiodataProvider().getBiodata(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
setState((){
religion = snapshot.data!.data;
})
         
        });
                        print(' ini Agama $religion');
                        return Column(
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              snapshot.data!.data!.name.toString(),
                              style: bold5,
                            ),
                            DropdownButton(
                              hint: const Text('Religion'),
                              items: religion!.map((item) {
                                return DropdownMenuItem(
                                  value: item.nmAgama.toString(),
                                  child: Text(item.idAgama.toString()),
                                );
                              }).toList(),
                              onChanged: (newVal) {
                                setState(() {
                                  dropdownAgama = newVal;
                                });
                              },
                              value: dropdownAgama,
                            ),
                          ],
                        );
                      } else {
                        return const Text('No Data');
                      }
                    }),
```

hope this helps!

Comment: I managed to display the data, but the response in the console log continues without stopping

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

- In Controller Class,

  - Initialize your **Future Method** as your Model :  `Future<List<LeaveModel>> getLeaves(){}`
  - create a List of Obj for **Custom Class** like this :
    `List<LeaveModel> leaveTypeObjList = [];`
  - After fetching data from API add the datas in obj list via Object

type :`LeaveModel leaveTypeObj =  LeaveModel(leaveTypeResponseList[i]["LEAVE_TYPE_EN"]);`

- And in loop add it to your obj list: `leaveTypeObjList.add(leaveTypeObj);`

** In widget class at **AsyncSnapshot** use your **List of Generics** like this :
`AsyncSnapshot<List<LeaveModel>>`.

## Demo Code

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main(List<String> args) {
  runApp(MyHome());
}

class MyHome extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHome({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyApp(),
    );
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  List<String> leaveTypeList = [];
  int currentLeaveType = 0;
  String? value;
  String? selectedLeaveType;
  late Future<List<LeaveModel>> futureLeaves;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureLeaves = FoodTypeController().getLeaves();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Text(
              "Leave Type =   ",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0),
            ),
            FutureBuilder(
                future: futureLeaves,
                builder: ((BuildContext context,
                    AsyncSnapshot<List<LeaveModel>> snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    leaveTypeList = [];
                    List<LeaveModel>? LeaveTypes = snapshot.data;

                    for (int i = 0; i < LeaveTypes!.length; i++) {
                      leaveTypeList.add(LeaveTypes[i].leaveTypes!);
                    }

                    return SizedBox(
                      width: 200,
                      height: 50,
                      child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 2.0, right: 4.0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 1)),
                        child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                          child: DropdownButton<String>(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                            value: currentLeaveType == null? null: leaveTypeList[currentLeaveType],
                            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down_rounded),
                            items: leaveTypeList.map(buildMenuItem).toList(),
                            onChanged: (value) => setState(() {
                              currentLeaveType = leaveTypeList.indexOf(value.toString());
                              this.value = value;

                              selectedLeaveType = this.value;
                            }),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return const Text("Error to load Snapshot");
                  } else {
                    return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                  }
                })),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  DropdownMenuItem<String> buildMenuItem(String item) => DropdownMenuItem(
        value: item,
        child: Text(
          item.toString(),
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, fontSize: 24.0),
        ),
      );
}

class LeaveModel {
  String? leaveTypes;
  LeaveModel(this.leaveTypes);
}

class FoodTypeController {
  Future<List<LeaveModel>> getLeaves() async {
    List<LeaveModel> leaveTypeObjList = [];

    String url = "";

    http.Response response =
        await http.post(Uri.parse(url), body: {"user": "", "pass": ""});

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      List leaveTypeResponseList = jsonDecode(response.body);

      for (int i = 0; i < leaveTypeResponseList.length; i++) {
        LeaveModel leaveTypeObj =
            LeaveModel(leaveTypeResponseList[i]["LEAVE_TYPE"]);
        leaveTypeObjList.add(leaveTypeObj);
      }
      return leaveTypeObjList;
    } else {
      throw Exception("Error to load data in Leave Controller");
    }
  }
}
```

## Response

[image: di]

## Visual

[image: ezgif-4-42fcba32ba]